# Getting different outputs using getMonth()

Tags: javascript, validation, date, object

I'm trying to use this function to validate if the user has 18 years or more, but i'm getting erratic behavior when using getMonth() . i.e. if I put 1, ir returns 0, but if I put 2, it returns 2:

```
function validacion() {
var anio = parseInt($('#year').val()); //year
var mes = parseInt($('#month').val()); //month
var dia = parseInt($('#day').val()); //day
var convertirMes = mes-1;
var ObjFechaFicticia = new Date();
var setearAnioFicticio = ObjFechaFicticia.setFullYear(anio); //year user input
var setearMesFicticio = ObjFechaFicticia.setMonth(convertirMes); //month user input
var setearDiasFicticio = ObjFechaFicticia.setDate(dia); //day user input

var ObjFechaActual = new Date();
var anioActual = ObjFechaActual.getFullYear();
var mesActual = ObjFechaActual.getMonth()+1;
var diaActual = ObjFechaActual.getDate();

console.log("Fecha real: "+diaActual+'/'+mesActual+'/'+anioActual)
console.log("Fecha ficticia :"+ObjFechaFicticia.getDate()+"/"+ObjFechaFicticia.getMonth()+"/"+ObjFechaFicticia.getFullYear())
```

}

Comment: Keep in mind that `Date.getMonth()` returns 0-based dates, (i.e. March is 2, April is 3), see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your issue is here:

```
var ObjFechaFicticia = new Date();
var setearAnioFicticio = ObjFechaFicticia.setFullYear(anio); //year user input
var setearMesFicticio = ObjFechaFicticia.setMonth(convertirMes); //month user input
var setearDiasFicticio = ObjFechaFicticia.setDate(dia); //day user input
```

When you do *setYear*, if the day number doesn't exist in the year that the Date is set to, it rolls over to the next month, e.g.

```
var d = new Date(2016, 1, 29); // 29 Feb 2016
d.setFullYear(2017);
```

There is no 29 Feb in 2017, so the date rolls over to 1 March. Now when you set the month, you'll get the first of that month, not the 29th which you might have been expecting.

The same thing will happen with *setMonth*, so even if you go from say 31 Aug 2018 to 31 Aug 2017, if you then set the month to June it will roll over to 1 July, and when you set the date it will be in July, not June as you might have expected.

The solution is to set all the parts in one go. And since you don't need the returned value, don't store it:

```
ObjFechaFicticia.setFullYear(anio, convertirMes, dia);
```

Now you'll only have an issue if *dia* doesn't exist in the new month. Hopefully you've already sorted that.

But you don't need to use the *set* methods anyway, just pass the values directly to the Date constructor:

```
var ObjFechaFicticia = new Date(anio, convertirMes, dia);
```

Which avoids all those issues. Your code might be:

```js
function $(s) {
  return document.querySelector(s);
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('calcButton').addEventListener('click', validacion, false);
}

function validacion() {
  var anio = parseInt($('#year').value); //year
  var mes = parseInt($('#month').value); //month
  var dia = parseInt($('#day').value); //day
  var convertirMes = mes-1;
  var ObjFechaFicticia = new Date(anio, convertirMes, dia); //day user input

  var ObjFechaActual = new Date();
  var anioActual = ObjFechaActual.getFullYear();
  var mesActual = ObjFechaActual.getMonth()+1;
  var diaActual = ObjFechaActual.getDate();

  console.log("Fecha real: "+diaActual+'/'+mesActual+'/'+anioActual);
  console.log("Fecha ficticia :"+ObjFechaFicticia.getDate()+"/"+ObjFechaFicticia.getMonth()+"/"+ObjFechaFicticia.getFullYear());
}
```

```html
Year: <input value="2016" id="year"><br>
Month: <input value="02" id="month"><br>
Day: <input value="29" id="day"><br>
<button id="calcButton">Do stuff</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because of the order in which way you are changing the date object ... today, 31/8/2018

lets say you want to put in a date of 4 feb 2018

```js
const outputDate = d => {
  console.log(`${d.getFullYear()}, ${d.getMonth() + 1}, ${d.getDate()}`);
}
var d = new Date();
outputDate(d); // d is 2018, 8, 31
d.setFullYear(2001);
outputDate(d); // d is 2000, 8, 31 
d.setMonth(1); // set february
outputDate(d); // d is 2000, 3, 3 // 3 is March!!
d.setDate(4);
outputDate(d); // d is 2000, 3, 4 // 3 is March!!
console.log(d+'');
```

now, if you change day, then month, then year

```js
const outputDate = d => {
  console.log(`${d.getFullYear()}, ${d.getMonth() + 1}, ${d.getDate()}`);
}
var d = new Date();
outputDate(d);
d.setDate(4);
outputDate(d);
d.setMonth(1); // set february
outputDate(d);
d.setFullYear(2001);
outputDate(d);
console.log(d+'');
```

Of course, you SHOULD just do

```
 var ObjFechaFicticia = new Date(anio, convertirMes, dia);
```

and all will be sweet